# If any ideal in $R$ is principal, then any ideal in $R \times R$ is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $R$ be a ring. We endow $R \times R$ with pointwise addition and pointwise multiplication. Then it's easy to verify that $R \times R$ is a ring under these operations. Then I conjecture that

> If any ideal in $R$ is principal, then any ideal in $R \times R$ is principal.

Could you please verify if my conjecture and attempt to prove it are correct? Thank you so much for your help!

---

> **Lemma:** Let $\sigma:R_1 \to R_2$ be a ring epimorphism and $I$ an ideal in $R_1$. Then $\sigma(I)$ is an ideal in $R_2$. Moreover, if $I$ is principal in $R_1$, then $\sigma(I)$ is principal in $R_2$.

*Proof:* It's straightforward to verify this lemma.

Let $I$ be an ideal in $R \times R$. Let $I_1,I_2$ be the sets of first and second coordinates of $I$ respectively. Consider the maps $\sigma_1: R \times R \to R, (r_1,r_2) \mapsto r_1$ and $\sigma_2: R \times R \to R, (r_1,r_2) \mapsto r_2$.

It's easy to verify that $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are ring epimorphism. By **Lemma**, $\sigma_1(I_1)$ and $\sigma_2(I_2)$ are ideals in $R$. By hypothesis, $\sigma_1(I_1)$ and $\sigma_2(I_2)$ are principal. Then $\sigma_1(I_1) = \langle a_1 \rangle$ and $\sigma_2(I_2) = \langle a_2 \rangle$ for some $a_1,a_2 \in R$. It's straightforward to verify that $\langle (a_1,a_2) \rangle = I$.

---

**Update:** Throughout my question, $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Here I add the proof of $\langle (a_1,a_2) \rangle = I$.

---

Then there are $(a_1,y), (x,a_2) \in I$ such that $\sigma_1(a_1,y) = a_1$ and $\sigma_2(x,a_2) = a_2$. It follows from $(1,0) \cdot(a_1,y) + (0,1) \cdot(x,a_2) = (a_1,a_2)$ that $(a_1,a_2) \in I$.

Next we prove $\langle (a_1, a_2) \rangle = I$. For $(a,b) \in I$, we have $a = xa_1$ and $b=ya_2$ for some $x,y \in R$. As such, $(a,b) = (x,y) \cdot (a_1,a_2)$. This completes the proof.

Comment: The most important step is the step you didn't write out, that $\langle (a_1, a_2) \rangle = I$!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Let me add it :))

Comment: Also if $R$ isn't commutative you should specify whether these are left, right, or two-sided ideals.

Comment: @Gae.S. I'm sorry, $\sigma$ should be a ring **epimorphism**.

Comment: It should be that $\sigma$ is a surjection! $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$ is an epimorphism.

Comment: Also, I presume you are talking about rings with unity? Because the claim is altogether not true for rngs (rings without unit), therefore you should use existence of $1$ in the second part of the lemma.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yeap, $R$ is a commutative ring with unity.

Comment: @Gae.S. I've just re-checked and found that the multiplicative identity may be not necessary for the proof. Please check my reasoning: Assume that $I = \langle a \rangle$ for some $a \in R_1$ and $\sigma(a) = b \in R_2$. Let $c \in \sigma(I)$. Then $c = \sigma(d)$ for some $d \in I$. We have $d = xa$ for some $x \in R_1$. Then $c = \sigma(xa) = \sigma(x)\sigma(a) = \sigma(x)b$. Hence $\sigma(I) = \langle b \rangle=\langle \sigma(a) \rangle$.

Comment: @Gae.S. I know you were there. Please respond to my previous comment ^^

Comment: @LAD Though I admit that it is arguable whether or not extending the definition to rings without unity (rng) makes sense, the fact is that, for instance, any commutative group $(G,+)$ becomes a rng with the zero multiplication; the ideals are the subgroups and the ideals generated by a single element are the cyclic subgroups. Hence you run into the usual fact that product of cyclic groups needs not be cyclic, in which case the ideal $G\times G$ is not generated by a single element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More generally, the following is true. I want to emphasize that this is remarkable, because the corresponding claim about subgroups or normal subgroups of a product of groups is *not* true.

> **Proposition:** Let $R, S$ be two rings. Every left ideal $K$ of the product ring $R \times S$ is of the form $I \times J$ where $I$ is a left ideal of $R$ and $J$ is a left ideal of $S$. Furthermore $K = (r, s)$ is principal if and only if $I = (r)$ and $J = (s)$ are.

*Proof.* Let $e = (1, 0)$. Every element of $R \times S$ has a canonical decomposition $(r, s) = e(r, s) + (1 - e)(r, s)$ (this is just a fancy way of saying $(r, s) = (r, 0) + (0, s)$). If $K$ is a left ideal of $R \times S$, then (since $K$ is by hypothesis closed under left multiplication) this decomposition applies to every element of $K$ and occurs entirely in $K$, so we have

$$K = eK + (1 - e) K.$$

Now $eK$ is a left ideal $I$ of $R$ and $(1 - e) K$ is a left ideal $J$ of $S$ and we have $K = I \times J$ as desired (the notation is a little confusing here because we could equally well say $K = I \oplus J$). And this argument gives straightforwardly that if $K$ is the principal ideal generated by some $(r, s)$ then $eK$ is the principal ideal generated by $(r, 0)$ and $(1 - e) K$ is the principal ideal generated by $(0, s)$. $\Box$

In the commutative case, what this says is that every quotient ring of a product $R \times S$ of commutative rings is a product of quotients $R/I \times S/J$, and again, I want to emphasize that this is remarkable because the corresponding claim about quotients of a product of groups is not true.

(Further comments, feel free to ignore: geometrically the upshot is that the affine scheme $\text{Spec } R \times S$ is a *disjoint* union $\text{Spec } R \sqcup \text{Spec } S$; the disjointness here is a stronger condition than just the condition that we have a coproduct, it really means that any affine scheme mapping in disconnects into an affine scheme mapping into $\text{Spec } R$ and an affine scheme mapping into $\text{Spec } S$. See [extensive category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category) for more about this.)

Comment: In general, if K is a left ideal of a ring T and a∈T, Ka is a left ideal of T, but aK is not, unless aK=Ka because a is a central element (which is the case here for e=(1,0)). Still, may make things clearer to write Ke everywhere.

Comment: @Patrick: I guess it doesn't matter much either way in this case, since as you say the key point is that $e$ is central, but I need to multiply on the left to guarantee that $eK$ is contained in $K$.